# How to make a patternProperties field in a json schema mandatory?

Tags: json, jsonschema

This should be a pretty quick yes or no, but I haven't been able to find the answer on SO or elsewhere. I want to make a set of schemas with a nice hierarchical dependency scheme rooted at an `entity` schema. The schema I want is

```
{                                                        
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "entity",                                      
    "type": "object",                                    
    "patternProperties": {                               
       "^.+Id$": {                                 
             "type": "string"                          
        }                            
    },
    "required": [
        "^.+Id$"
    ]                                          
}
```

Basically, I want every entity, for example a Person, to require a field called `somethingId` (for person, probably `personId`). However, using "required" in this way seems to force an actual field named `"^.+Id$"` rather than that the object must have one field matching the pattern. Is there a way to do what I want here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a moment of inspiration and googled "patternrequired json schema," and it looks like this was a feature that didn't make it into draft v4, unfortunately for me. https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/issues/59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in your comment, you can not enforce dynamic property keys in the required clause.

But if you can allow for a nested definition, you can model your Identifier as follows:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "identifier" : {
            "additionalProperties" : false,
            "minProperties" : 1,
            "maxProperties" : 1,
            "patternProperties" : "^.+Id$ "
        }
    },
    "required": ["identifier"]
}
```

This way your identifier must have a unique property with a key validating your regex.

Comment: I think that's going to end up being the cleanest solution... it's a shame that the patternRequired field didn't make it into v4, though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved without changing data structure with this schema:

```
{
  "patternProperties" : {
    "^.+Id$": {                                 
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "minProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```